# Вывод данных циклом внутри цикла

Tags: php, mysql

На страницу выводится информация циклом foreach, а внутри есть еще такой же цикл который выводит другую информацию, но после внутреннего цикла, дальше выводятся данные только по внутреннему циклу.
Как его закончить и выводить далее данные только по первому циклу?
Код примерно такой:

```
<?php foreach ($result_day1 as $value) { ?>
  <p><?= $value['number'] ?></p>

   <?php foreach ($result_teachers as $value) { ?>
     <option class="schedule__teacher__name" name="<?= $value['teacher_id'] ?>" value=" 
     <?= $value['teacher_name'] ?>"><?= $value['teacher_name'] ?></option>
  <?php  } ?>
```

<-- далее должны выводится данные из цикла $result_day1, а выводятся из цикла $result_teachers-->

```
<div class="modal fade" id="deleteModal<?= $value['id'] ?><?= $value['group_kollege'] ? >" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

Comment: Элемент второго цикла назовите, например, `$teacher`, вместо `$value`.

Comment: Спасибо большое!!!